# node-gyp node-sass problem with using `npm install`

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass, node-gyp, node-sass

I have a problem related to `node-gyp`, `node-sass`.
I've just updated the `npm` from `6` to `8.19.4`. Everything used to work against the 6th version. However, now - after moving to `npm@8` - I see the error during `npm install` process.

I face the error below:

```
npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

```
npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.2
npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
```

I know it requires `python2.7`, though, I don't think it'd be a good solution to install one. Because it's deprecated. So is `node-sass`.

Globally, I have `v9.4.0` of **node-gyp** installed.

**My tryouts that haven't helped:**

1. Uninstall `node-sass`.

I don't have any direct dependency on `node-sass` in `package.json`, so it must be indirect. Regardless of that fact, I've tried to uninstall `node-sass` and use `sass`:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

I end up seeing the same error related to `python`.

2. Set the npm config

```
npm install --global node-gyp@latest
npm config set node_gyp $(npm prefix -g)/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
```

The script above hasn't helped me either.

When I check the config

```
npm config get node_gyp
```

I see

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
```

which means the variable is set, but it doesn't help anyway.

3. Update local `node-gyp`

I've also tried to update `node-gyp` which is a local copy of npm by

```
npm explore npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script -g -- npm_config_global=false npm install node-gyp@latest
```

No help.

4. Add `node-gyp` to the dev dependencies.

Added to `package.json`

```
"node-gyp": "^9.4.0",
```

No help.

5. Add `node-sass` to the dev deps.

Added to the `package.json`

```
"node-sass": "^6.0.1"
```

No help.

6. Check the tree dependencies.
   I've used an app to build the dependency tree. This thing hasn't helped either - I haven't found any library using `node-sass`.

**My guesses**:

1. I reckon that there is some indirect dependency that requires the old `node-sass` => it requires the old `node-gyp` => it requires the old `python2.7`. The update of the version of the first dependency should help. Though, I don't know which one eaxctly.
   *The package.json is presented below.*
2. Adding `python2` should resolve the issue as well, but I don't want to introduce anything new being deprecated into the app.

`Package.json dependencies`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.22.5",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.29.1",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.2.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.2.0",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.2.0",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.2.0",
    "@storybook/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.2.0",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.187",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "@types/progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "@types/rc-slider": "^8.6.6",
    "@types/react": "^16.13.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/speed-measure-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "dependency-cruiser": "^11.18.0",
    "envify": "^4.1.0",
    "esbuild-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "git-revision-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "ify-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-css-modules": "^2.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
    "jest-raw-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "jest-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "react-docgen-typescript-plugin": "^1.0.5",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.11",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "speed-measure-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "storybook": "^7.2.0",
    "storybook-css-modules": "^1.0.8",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "template-ejs-loader": "0.9.4",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.9",
    "ts-loader": "^8.4.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.88.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-shell-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "webpack-shell-plugin-next": "^2.3.1",
    "worker-loader": "^3.0.8"
  }
```

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^2.7.5",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid": "^2.7.5",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid-export": "^2.7.5",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui": "^2.7.5",
    "@dnd-kit/core": "^6.0.5",
    "@dnd-kit/sortable": "^7.0.1",
    "@dnd-kit/utilities": "^3.2.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.47",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^6.19.6",
    "@sentry/webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.2.0",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.9.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.32.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
    "@types/color-convert": "^2.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^28.2.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "^28.2.0",
    "ansi-to-react": "^5.0.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
    "codemirror": "^5.48.0",
    "color": "^4.2.3",
    "color-string": "^1.6.0",
    "comlink": "^4.3.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.3.2",
    "console-browserify": "^1.2.0",
    "csslint": "^1.0.5",
    "currency.js": "^1.1.4",
    "dagre": "^0.8.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.24.0",
    "diff": "^4.0.1",
    "diff2html": "^3.1.18",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "fast-deep-equal": "^2.0.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "filesize": "^3.6.1",
    "github-markdown-css": "^4.0.0",
    "hast-util-sanitize": "^3.0.0",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "htmlhint": "^1.1.4",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.7.0",
    "invert-color": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jshint": "^2.13.6",
    "jsoneditor": "^9.5.6",
    "jszip": "^3.7.0",
    "katex": "^0.12.0",
    "keymirror": "^0.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react": "^2.4.0",
    "luxon": "^1.3.2",
    "material-ui-search-bar": "^1.0.0-beta.13",
    "mathjs": "^7.6.0",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "npm": "^6.14.18",
    "p-limit": "^2.1.0",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.2",
    "plotly.js": "2.11.1",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.12.1",
    "randomstring": "^1.3.0",
    "rc-slider": "^8.6.6",
    "rc-tooltip": "^3.7.3",
    "re-resizable": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-codemirror2": "^6.0.0",
    "react-color": "^2.17.3",
    "react-complex-tree": "^2.2.2",
    "react-contenteditable": "^3.2.6",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.2.1",
    "react-document-title": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-draggable": "^4.1.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.13",
    "react-easy-crop": "^4.0.1",
    "react-flow-renderer": "^10.0.6",
    "react-grid-layout": "^1.2.5",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-highlight": "0.11.1",
    "react-hubspot-form": "^1.3.7",
    "react-image-crop": "^8.5.0",
    "react-intercom": "^1.0.14",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^8.24.1",
    "react-loaders": "^3.0.1",
    "react-mde": "git+https://github.com/comet-ml/react-mde.git",
    "react-papaparse": "^3.11.1",
    "react-placeholder": "^3.0.1",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-plotly.js": "2.5.1",
    "react-prismazoom": "^3.1.0",
    "react-query": "^3.34.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^1.2.0",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "react-spring": "9.4.5",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "react-svg-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^7.0.4",
    "react-tiny-virtual-list": "^2.2.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
    "react-window": "^1.8.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-form": "^8.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "rehype-highlight": "^4.0.0",
    "rehype-katex": "^4.0.0",
    "rehype-parse": "^7.0.1",
    "rehype-sanitize": "^4.0.0",
    "rehype-stringify": "^8.0.0",
    "remark": "^12.0.1",
    "remark-math": "^3.0.1",
    "remark-parse": "^8.0.3",
    "remark-rehype": "^7.0.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "semver": "^7.3.8",
    "showdown": "^1.9.1",
    "turndown": "^4.0.2",
    "unified": "^9.2.0",
    "use-deep-compare-effect": "^1.6.1",
    "use-route-as-state": "^5.1.1",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "wavesurfer.js": "^4.1.1"
  }
```

**Context**:

Everything works smoothly on `npm@6`.

**The versions:**

```
node-gyp: 9.4.0
node: 16.20.2
npm: 8.19.4
```

Thanks :)

Comment: That's when we look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass and see the giant warning that's telling us to _stop using node-sass_ and use https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass instead. `node-sass` has been deprecated for over 3 years now =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### **Update**

Found the root cause -- one of your installed module is dependent on `node-sass`, therefore you will run into the same issue regardless you removed `node-sass` in your `package.json` or not.

```
"react-mde": "git+https://github.com/comet-ml/react-mde.git",
```

---

#### Original

Like what you have encountered, due to the fact `node-sass` requires `node-gyp` which is notoriously difficult to get it working. Despite there are workaround, the general suggestion for this kinda problem is to, like you said already, to remove `node-sass` and just use `sass`.

Assuming we are using `sass` I suspect that your `node_module` directory and `package.lock.json` is outdated (perhaps you modified `package.json` manually somehow instead of running `npm install/uninstall`?).

Therefore, the easiest way to get past this work is replacing `node-sass` with `sass` with the following steps --

1. Make sure `node-sass` isn't in `package.json`, and `sass` is in it.
2. Remove `node_module/` and `package.lock.json`
3. run `npm install`
4. re-run the app.

And this should get you back on your feet.

If that doesn't work it prob means some other module you have installed in the app is also dependent on `node-gyp`.

Comment: thanks for your help :) i've already tried to remove `node-module`, `package-lock.json` and it  didnt help either :(

Comment: @AlexandreAdereyko just tested them myself. The root cause is `react-mde` as it has `node-sass` as one of dependency, so its gonna hit this error all the time you run `npm i`. You could try to remove that and find an alternative module to replace it. Perhaps the real `react-mde` as it doesn't have `node-sass` as dependency? https://github.com/andrerpena/react-mde

Comment: Saying that because this is what you have for `react-mde` -- `"react-mde": "git+https://github.com/comet-ml/react-mde.git",`, which is a forked version of the official `react-mde`

Comment: thanks a lot, you've saved my day!
question: maybe you can let me know, how did you find this indirect dependency? or you juse knew it

Comment: Thanks for the good words! Half of how i know it comes from experience (wasn't a fun moment), and half of it comes from luck (was personally installing/uninstalling the package locally, tho i am sure there's a better way that i ma unaware of)